# Why the positive sample size in the confusion metrics is smaller than the actual data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I was doing logistic regression for my coupon dataset, and the coupon.flag.value_counts() shows there are 22356 negative samples and 2961 positive samples. But after building the logistic regression model, the total amount of positive samples in the training confusion metric is only 51.(test_size = 0.3) Can someone help me to figure out what's the problem here? Thanks!

```
coupon=pd.read_csv('L2_Week3.csv')
coupon=pd.get_dummies(coupon)
coupon.flag.value_counts()
0    22356
1     2961
Name: flag, dtype: int64

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
y=coupon['flag']
x=coupon[['coupon_used_in_last_month','job_retired','job_student','marital_single','returned_yes','job_bl
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=100)
from sklearn import linear_model
lr=linear_model.LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred_train=lr.predict(x_train)
y_pred_test=lr.predict(x_test)
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train,y_pred_train)

Out[96]:
array([[15589,    34],
       [ 2081,    17]])
```

As I said, the numbers for positive samples in the metric just is way smaller than the actual data.

Comment: That is the number of samples your classifier classified as positive (as opposed to the number of samples that were *actually* positive = 2081 + 17 = 2098 ~ 2072 = (1 - 0.3)*2961).  It's not exact bc your split is simple random and not stratified.

Comment: Looks like some of your code got cutoff on the `x=coupon[[...` line

Comment: Thank you guys!! I figured out why...Also,  do you know how to use stratified sampling? Like 50% positive samples and 50% negative samples, then split the data set.

Comment: Just use the option `stratify=y` in `train_test_split`.

Comment: Thanks! I used this but the training data is still not balanced. I guess I want to split data first then I balance the training set. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression gives probabilities as the result, not pure 0 and 1. In such kind of prediction you should find a threshold (using valid dataset) to decide which probability will be treated as 0 and which as 1 to obtain the best value of your metric (accuracy, precision, etc.), and then use this threshold on test predictions. If you do not do this operation, a confusion matrix is generated using the default threshold (0.5), which is a bad idea, because even without any further optimization, the threshold should be set as the ratio of 1's in the dataset, i.e. 2961/(2961+22356).

Try to use this code:

```py
    threshold = 2961/(2961+22356)
    metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train,(y_pred_train>threshold).astype(int))
```

Notabene, this operation is not needed to evaluate AUC, which operates both on probabilities and pure 0 and 1. It is worth to know, that predicted probabilities converted to 0 and 1 give usually much worse AUC than raw probabilities.